# Can I combine a Mystery/Meltan box with an incense?

Tags: pokemon-go

Both the incense and Mystery Box spawns extra Pokemon. Even with the current extra spawns from the incense, I am waiting in between spawns when I am sitting at home. I would like to combine an incense with a Mystery Box so that I have more spawns, and can actually continue catching for a full hour. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is **not possible**.

If you have an active incense, and open up a Mystery Box, the animation is working correctly so you might think it worked, but what is actually happening is that you consume another incense. This means that your incense duration is another hour longer, one incense is removed from your inventory, and not more spawns per minute.

If you have an active Mystery Box, you get an error message when trying to apply a lure. This is probably because you do not have another Mystery Box in your inventory.

No matter the order, it does not yield you more spawns per minute, so you have to be happy with the current number of spawns per minute.

Comment: An alternative strategy for obtaining more spawns is to combine a Mystery box with a Lure Module.

Comment: That's also a good idea. Not within the range of a Pokestop unfortunately (not even with the increased range). Within the range of a gym though, which yields more benefits.